# Windows Builder GUI on Ecllipse not working

Tags: eclipse, gui

I wanted to work on GUI in Eclipse. I tried installing Window Builder and swing files through Eclipse. When I create a new application window class I can see the source code but when I go into the design tab there are no GUI tools to work with, it is all blank.

[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OgAo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You class must extend a Swing or AWT container. In your exemple, make your class extend JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cinema extends JFrame{
...
```